# Next.js original imported modules run before mock imported modules, trying perform client-side actions

Tags: javascript, next.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to run a jest test on a next.js react page that fetchs information from the url and stores it locally in the browser cache.

Currently for some reason the component for testing imports the original modules while ignoring any of my attempts to mock that module. Leading to test suite failed to run error.

The test and the component are in the same folder.

I have tried mocking `@/app/config/client` and using `jest.enableAutomock();` and `jest.mock('@/app/store/index.ts'` but the component still seems to import the original `import { useAccessStore } from "@/app/store"` and crashes since server variables aren’t loaded for testing

Also the error happens at line 10, though I do not have any functions at line 10

at Object. (app/auth/link/page.test.jsx:10:16)

- component code

  ```
  //page.ts
  "use client";
  import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import { useAccessStore } from "@/app/store";

  export default function AuthLinkPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();

    const access = useAccessStore();
    const [authLink, setauthLink] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
      // Convert all searchParams to a JSON string and save in authLink local persistant store
      const params: Record<string, string> = {};
      searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
        params[key] = value;
      });
      const paramsJsonString = JSON.stringify(params);
      setauthLink(paramsJsonString);
      access.updateLinkAuth(paramsJsonString);
      console.log("[authlink received]", paramsJsonString);
      // Redirect to home or dashboard after setting the authLink
      router.push("/");
    }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Processing your authentication link...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  ```
- testing code

  ```
  jest.enableAutomock();

  jest.mock('@/app/config/client', () => {
      return {
          getClientConfig: jest.fn(() => {
              // Return a mock configuration object
              return { /* mock configuration properties */ };
          })
      };
  });
  console.log("useaccessstore0", useAccessStore)

  import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
  import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
  import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
  import { expect, jest, test } from '@jest/globals';
  import { useAccessStore } from "@/app/store";
  console.log("useaccessstore1", useAccessStore)

  jest.mock('@/app/store/index.ts', () => {
      return {
          // Mock implementations or import them from your mock file
          chat: jest.fn(),
          update: jest.fn(),
          access: jest.fn(),
          config: jest.fn()
      };
  });
  console.log("useaccessstore2", useAccessStore)
  jest.mock("next/navigation");

  describe.only('Page', () => {

      useSearchParams.mockReturnValue({
          version: "1.0",
          permission: "User",
          expiry: 1807097101,
          salt: "sampleHashSalt",
      })

      it('calls useAcess store', () => {
          console.log("useaccessstore3", useAccessStore)
          render(<AuthLinkPage />);
          console.log("useaccessstore4", useAccessStore)
          expect(useAccessStore).toHaveBeenCalled();
          // Additional assertions...
      });

      it('renders a heading', () => {
          render(<AuthLinkPage />)

          const processingText = screen.getByText('Processing your authentication link...')

          expect(processingText).toBeInTheDocument()
      })
  })
  ```
- Error

  ```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

    4 |   if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
    5 |     // client side
  > 6 |     return JSON.parse(queryMeta("config")) as BuildConfig;
      |                 ^
    7 |   }
    8 |
    9 |   if (typeof process !== "undefined") {

    at getClientConfig (app/config/client.ts:6:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/store/config.ts:35:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/locales/cn.ts:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/locales/index.ts:31:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/components/ui-lib.tsx:72:57)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/utils.ts:53:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/store/chat.ts:25:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/store/index.ts:5:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/auth/link/page.test.jsx:10:16)
  ```
- best guesses to the issue

  - Somehow before this component is created, the mainpage component is created and imports from useAccess store
  - Something to do with client side code with the UseEffect function